# How to add comments on django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to add a comment system to my project, all the code looks fine but I am getting this error "ValueError at /
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing". I dont know what is wrong but the error might be on the views.py file.

views.py

```
    def imagelist(request):
        images = Post.objects.all()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=images)
        if request.method == 'POST':
          comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
          if comment_form.is_valid():
            contentt = request.POST.get('content')
            comment = Comment.objects.create(post=images, user=request.user, content=content)
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        else:
          comment_form = CommentForm()
        context2 = {
            "images": images,
            "comments": comments,
            "comment_form": comment_form,
        }
return render(request, 'imagelist.html', context2)
```

models.py

```
    class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title.str(self.user.username))

    class Post(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        posti = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images', null=True, blank="True")
        video = models.FileField(upload_to='media/images', null=True, blank="True")
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='imageuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='username')
        liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked')
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.tittle)
```

forms.py

```
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ('content',)
```

Comment: Can you share the *full* traceback?

Comment: Also the `__str__` method is wrong, change `format` method arguments with `self.post.title, str(self.user.username)`

Comment: There is something strange with this view, you list all `Post` objects, but when you make a POST request to create a new comment, then your view does not know on what `Post` you are making a comment.

Comment: @DenizKaplan fixing that on the models didnt change anything, can you please explain to me better what can I do on the views or post an answer please?

Comment: I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/61900155/2474573 this is the answer, try that and update your question wtih traceback you have got if you cannot achieve what you aimed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 hours of searching for answers, this is how I achieve it. All I did was add this new view, method, url and html. Hope this helps!

views.py

```
     def imagedetail(request, pk):
       post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
       comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
       if request.method == 'POST':
         comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
         if comment_form.is_valid():
           content = request.POST.get('content')
           comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
           comment.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())

       else:
         comment_form = CommentForm()
       context2 = {
          "comments": comments,
          "comment_form": comment_form,
       }
       return render(request, 'imagedetail.html', context2)
```

models.py (on Post model)

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('imagedetail', args=[self.id])
```

urls.py (for new view which is imagedetail)

```
    path('imagedetail/<int:pk>/', views.imagedetail, name='imagedetail'),
```

imagelist.html (to redirect to imagedetail, btw it is a bootstrap button)

```
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'imagedetail' pk=image.pk %}"></a>
```

imagedetail.html (it only shows comments)

```
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{comment_form.as_p}}
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-succes">
      {% else %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-succes" disabled>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
    <div class="main-comment-section">
      {{ comments.count }}
      {% for comment in comments %}
        <blockquote class="blockquote">
            <p class="mb-0">{{ comment.content }}</p>
            <footer class="blockquote-footer">by <cite title="Source Title">{{ comment.user }}</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass to the `create` mathod of the comments a single `Post` since the corresponding fields is a `ForeignKey` and you're passing an entire queryset (`Post.objects.all()`)

You need get just the post where the comment should live.

```py
single_post = Post.objects.get(pk=the_post_pk)
comment = Comment.objects.create(post=single_post, user=request.user, content=content)
```

Comment: Yes, Also I saw now that `get_object_or_404` is wrong, you need an extra param see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you write:

```
images = Post.objects.all()
comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=images)
```

Here `images` is a set of `Post` objects, not a single `Post` object, hence you can not filter on that. But you actually do *not* need to do this anyway.

Furthermore there is also a small mistake in the `__str__` of your `Comment` model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.text, self.user.username)
```

But the view itself looks "odd", since you here write a list of `Post`s, but if you make a POST request, you will somehow need to know to what post you want to submit the `Comment`, therefore at least the view that accepts the POST request, will need to know the primary key of the `Post` to comment on. You can for example encode that in the `urls.py`:

```
# appname/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/', views.post_list, name='post_detail')
]
```

In that view, we can then fetch the item, for example with `get_object_or_404`, and in case of a POST set the `post` and `user` objects in the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def post_detail(request, pk):
    image = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
          comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.user = request.user
            comment_form.instance.post = image
            comment_form.save()
            return redirect(post)
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'post': image,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'imagedetail.html', context)
```

In your template, you can render the comments of the post with:

```
{{ post }}
{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
    {{ comment }}
{% endfor %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ comment_form }}
</form>
```

you can also make a view that renders a list:

```
@login_required
def post_list(request, pk):
    images = Post.objects.prefetch_related('comment_set')
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'image': images,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'imagelist.html', context)
```

in the template for the list, you can render it with:

```
{% for post in images %}
    {{ post }}
    {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
        {{ comment }}
    {% endfor %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.pk %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form }}
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

here we thus make a POST request to the `post-detail` view.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214220/discussion-on-answer-by-willem-van-onsem-how-to-add-comments-on-django).

Answer (score 0):

2 - forms.py icine elave ele:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment   
fields = ('name', 'body')

# overriding default form setting and adding bootstrap class
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs = {'placeholder': 'Enter name', 'class': 'form-control'}
    self.fields['body'].widget.attrs = {'placeholder': 'Comment here...', 'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}
```

3 - models.py elave ele :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField()

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_comments(self):
    return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self).filter(active=True)
```

4 - views.py post bele gorunmelidi :

```
def post (request,slug):
post = Post.objects.get(slug = slug)
latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
new_comment = None
comment_form = CommentForm()


comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
if comment_form.is_valid():
    new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
    new_comment.post = post
    new_comment.save()
    comment_form = CommentForm()

context = {
    'post': post,
    'latest': latest,
    'comments': comments,
    'comment_form': comment_form
}
return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

5 - post.html de author altina divider den sonra elave ele :

```
    <hr/>
    <h3>Add Comment</h3>
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
    </form>

    {% with comments.count as total_comments %}
        <h3 class="mt-5">
            {{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}
        </h3>
    {% endwith %}
    {% if not post.comments.all %}
        No comments yet

    {% else %}
        {% for comment in post.get_comments %}
            {% include 'comment.html' with comment=comment %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

6 - admin.py elave ele :

```
@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display=('name', 'post', 'created', 'active')
list_filter = ('active', 'created', 'updated')
search_fields = ('name', 'body')
```

7 - templates de comment.html yarat ve icine elave et :

```
<div class="border-0 border-start border-2 ps-2" id="{{comment.id}}">

    <div class="mt-3">
        <strong>{{comment.name}}</strong>
        {% if  comment.parent.name%} to <strong>{{comment.parent.name}}</strong>{% endif %}
        <small class="text-muted">On {{ comment.created.date }}</small>
    </div>
    <div class="border p-2 rounded">
        <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="handleReply({{comment.id}})">Reply</button>

        <div id="reply-form-container-{{comment.id}}" style="display:none">

           
        </div>
    </div>
    {% for comment in comment.get_comments %}
        {% include 'comment.html' with comment=comment %}
    {% endfor %}
```

8 - models de post un altina elave ele

```
def get_comments(self):
    return self.comments.filter(parent=None).filter(active=True)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).